# URL Redirection in Haproxy.cfg

Tags: haproxy

I am trying to redirect a URL in my haproxy.cfg file and not sure where to start. What my goal is whenever I go to https://website/text it gets redirected to https://website/#/text/conversation and same thing with voice. How exactly can I do this? I am using HAProxy version 1.5.14. Below is what I have (tried), but it's not working as I want it to.

```
frontend HTTPS_IN
acl host_connect hdr(host) -i website.com
acl path_voice path_beg -i /voice
redirect location https://website/#/voice/voicemail if path_voice
acl path_text path_beg -i /text
redirect location https://website/#/text/conversation if path_text
use_backend voice if path_voice
use backend voice if host_connect
use_backend text if path_text
```

Am I on the right path at all? If not, can you guys please help me out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you set the host_connect acl if it connects to website.com. Nothing changes this later so it will always match `use backend voice if host_connect` So I expect you are always going to end up at the voice backend.

Try doing this instead:

```
frontend HTTPS_IN
acl path_voice path_beg -i /voice
redirect location https://website/#/voice/voicemail if path_voice
acl path_text path_beg -i /text
redirect location https://website/#/text/conversation if path_text
use_backend voice unless path_text
```

Comment: That was a typo, sorry, I want it to be path_beg -i /voice like path_beg -i /text.

Comment: Am I correct that all requests are going to the voice backend because of the host_connect line? You can also edit your question to fix the typo

Comment: Thank you, I edited the OP. So I have two backends, for voice and text. So the text portion is going to the text backend and voice and host_connect is going to voice backend. Host_connect is going to voice because I want when someone goes to https://website.com to go to the voice page, so that or /voice will go to the voice page.

Comment: The problem is that if someone goes to https://website.com/text you will have host_connect acl set (because hdr(host) doesn't care what the URL is) and path_text acl set, but it will go to the voice backend because it matches the host_connect acl. It would be better to remove the host_connect acl (and it's associated use_backend line) and add a default_backend line for anything that doesn't match the path_voice and path_text acls.  You could also remove the path_voice acl and only have the path_text acl and then change your last three lines to `use_backend voice unless path_text`

Comment: Do you mean something like this? `acl path_text path_beg -i /text
  use_backend voiceqa unless path_text default_backend voiceqa` Also what happens with the redirection?

Comment: You're right. Leave the acls in for the redirection. Then use the unless line at the end. I edited my answer above with the suggestion.

Comment: So I tried what you suggested. When I go to https://website.com/text though it is still going to the voice section...